# signatureOrSystem protection level in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am pretty new in Android Studio. I am trying to add a permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
```

The problem I am facing is that apparently my app is NON system app. I read about the differences between system and NON system apps. However I didn't get to any solution.
My question is: How to sign an app by platform signature? Can anyone explain that please? And maybe explain why do I need to do that?
I know that my question might look very silly, but as I mentioned, I just started to use Android Studio so I am pretty new in all that and I need some help with silly things like this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: How to sign an app by platform signature?

Build your own custom Android ROM. You will sign that platform, and you can then sign your app with the same signing key. Of course, you will only get this permission when your app is running on devices that, in turn, are running your custom ROM.

> And maybe explain why do I need to do that?

Because you are trying to use a `signature`-level permission to control the OS. Approximately 1 in 50,000 Android developers need to do this, and usually only in conjunction with creating their own custom Android ROM.

IOW, to quote [the documentation for this permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES): "Not for use by third-party applications".